# Fermat's last theorem of form a^b^c mod n

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to solve the following equation for homework: 14^47^87 mod 73. I'm supposed to use fermat's last theorem to solve this, and i can solve the regular ones with only one exponent fairly easy, but i don't know how to approach this one.

I've tried to rewrite the expression as 14^(72-25)^87 mod 73 => (1 / 14^25)^87 mod 73, but i doubt that is the way to go. Could anyone please explain to me how to approach this problem?

Comment: I think you mean "Fermat's Little Theorem".  Well, what does that say?  In this case, it says that $14^{72}\equiv 1\pmod {73}$, so you just need to sort out what $47^{87}\pmod {72}$ is.

Comment: Parentheses are important here, because `a^(b^c)` is not generally equal to `(a^b)^c`.  See this [introduction to posting mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), where exponents and subscripts are some of the simpler constructs to use.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how the theorem can be used to infer 47^87 (mod 72)? Why 72 and not 73?